# Xamarin Forms Icons

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, glyphicons

I'm wondering how I can implement icons inside my Xamarin Forms app. I want to use something like glyphicons or font awesome. However, I have no idea how to implement it into my xaml/c# pages.

Ideally, I am aiming for something like this:

[image]

If someone could provide the code to display an icon like the search bar or three lines, that would be great. I can format it to look pretty. I'm struggling with how to actually pull in the icon!

Comment: Google turns up several hits of packages to support this.  Did you even try searching first?

Comment: Yes, everything I've seen requires custom rendering and techniques that I cannot grasp. Iconize doesnt seem like it would work for windows phones. Could you please provide the names of packages that work for iOS, Android, and UWP?

Comment: @ConnorMeeks can you please see my answer, that is how I implemented it for the first time couple of years ago, very nice and easy and you don't need to be a Xamarin expert.

Comment: For custom fonts in xamarin forms you can use this [Blog](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/using-custom-fonts-on-ios-and-android-with-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: You can used the derived Unicodes here: https://github.com/fzany/Font-Awesome-Cheat-Charp

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way may be is to use https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins

From Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio, install the following packages:

- Xam.Plugin.Iconize
- Xam.Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome
- Xam.FormsPlugin.Iconize

Note: you can install Xam.Plugin.Iconize.Material and many others similar if you want to.

In the Android project, MainActivity class, OnCreate() method add

```
FormsPlugin.Iconize.Droid.IconControls.Init(Resource.Id.toolbar);
Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.With(new Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.FontAwesomeModule());
```

In the iOS project, AppDelegate class, FinishedLaunching() method, add similar lines

```
FormsPlugin.Iconize.iOS.IconControls.Init();
Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.With(new Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.FontAwesomeModule())
```

Also, in the iOS project, info.plist add

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>     
    <string>iconize-fontawesome.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Now, in your XAML where you have your toolbar, in  tag, add

```
<ContentPage ...
xmlns:iconize="clr-namespace:FormsPlugin.Iconize;assembly=FormsPlugin.Iconize" ...
>
```

and

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <iconize:IconToolbarItem Order="Primary" Clicked="..." Icon="fa-search" IconColor="White" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: will this work for Windows (UWP)? is there anything I have to do for those files?

Comment: will this work for Windows? or is this Android/iOS specific?

Comment: Not sure about Windows.

Comment: Tried this for UWP, and sadly it does not work for commandbar icons

Comment: I am visualizing the icons but it does nothing when I click it.  in Iconlabel it is working fine.  And also the toolbaritem for iOS is ok

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle How to display this icon in Label text?

Comment: this is deprecated now

Answer (score 5):

Look at the new release of Xamarin Forms, the solution was made! I posted the anwser in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56257444/11305148

But there it go. The follow code works just fine:

```
<Button  Text="Pesquisar">
    <Button.ImageSource>
         <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf002;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontIcon}"/>
    </Button.ImageSource>
</Button>
```

And this too:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
             <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf002;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontIcon}"/>
        </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```